# How can I start the creation of a Django foreign key model instance from the parent form?

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, django-admin

I created the following two Django models:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length  =   100,
        null        =   False
    )
    zip_code = models.CharField(
        max_length  =   10,
        null        =   False
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Partners"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Screen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length  =   100,
        null        =   False
    )
    position = models.CharField(
        max_length  =   100,
        help_text   =   "Google Pluscode",
        null        =   False
    )
    partner = models.ForeignKey(
        Partner,
        on_delete   =   models.PROTECT,
        null        =   False
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Screens"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I add a new instance of a screen, I would like to be able to click on a button inside the form and add a new instance of a partner (if it does not exist yet). After the creation of the foreign key instance, it should return to the original form. It is the same mechanism as in the the admin site when you add a new instance of a model (see image below) but I don't know how to implement it.

[Admin site model creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xr2X.png)

I have already looked up inline forms but this is not really the mechanism I want to use. I want to have a new HTML-Page or a modal for the second form.

Comment: Have you tried using `ModelForm` same as in django admin, inheriting it should be doing the tirck. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#interaction-with-model-validation

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm already using ModelForm for the forms of the two models. I can create instances of both models separately.. I only don't know how to write the function to create a foreign key instance from the first form